# php registration form , add more columns in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, registration

I made a simple registration form, but when i add more columns in phpmyadmin i can't register a user it says 'Registration Unsuccessful due to server error. Please try later'.
Thanks for help.

```
    if($password==$cpassword)
    {
      $query = "select * from user where username='$username'";
      $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
      if($query_run)
      {
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0)
        {
          echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("This Username Already exists.. Please try another username!")</script>';
        }
        else
        {
          $query = "insert into user values('$username','$password')";
          $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
          if($query_run)
          {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
            // header( "Location: profile.php");
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("User Registered.. Welcome")</script>';
          }
          else
          {
            echo '<p class="bg-danger msg-block">Registration Unsuccessful due to server error. Please try later</p>';
          }
        }
      }
      else
      {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("DB error")</script>';
      }
    }
    else
    {
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Password and Confirm Password do not match")</script>';
    }

  }
  else
  {
  }
?>
```

I tried to add different columns, nothing works, i think i just have to change the $query function or something.For example it works when i have only username and password columns but doesn't work when i add the user_id or date when user was created. What is wrong with that form?

Comment: I think when you add more columns you mark them as `not null` in `PhpMyAdmin` that's why when the insert query is executed it throws an exception and that
`if($query_run)` returns `false` hence **Registration unsuccessful..** is echoed

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is when you inserted the column `user_id` you forgot to set its key to primary key and set it to auto increment, i assume in your query that the table only has username and password fields so there is no process or insertion of the user_id so your query is returning an error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i found out what was the problem, so simple, I just had to change :

```
$query = "insert into user values(NULL,'$username','$password')";
```

Since the id column is of type AUTO_INCREMENT, and MySQL will decide what value to assigb acording to the next available number in sequence. I read this in:
learning php mysql and javascript robin nixon.
Thanks anyway.